# Which command in VBA can count the number of characters in a string variable?

Tags: vba, count, variables, command, character

Let's say I have this variable:

word = "habit"

which command in VBA will allow me to count how many characters are there in this variable (in my case it's 5).

Important: the variable "word" contains only one word, no spaces, but may have contain numbers and hyphens.

Comment: By "characters", do you mean letters only? Technically, a string variable can contain digits, hyphens, punctuation, and so forth; those are still "characters". Your question is very poorly phrased. Please edit and clarify exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I understand that the author's question is filled with ambiguity.  However, I remember what it feels like to not even know the terminology to even *begin* to be able to ask a question.  Perhaps by "variable" he means "string" and by "number of characters" he means the length of the string.  I remember what it felt like to be perplexed to learn that strings and files had a "length" rather than a "count of characters" or "file size."  Hopefully the author has learned some new terminology from his post :)

Comment: bmccormark, you are absolutely right. I just learned that spaces, new lines, returns and tabs are also considered as characters! This is something that goes so much against my natural understanding! :)

Comment: I have a copy of *VBA Developer's Handbook* on my bookshelf at work.  It was written in 2001, but since all my VBA development has been for Office XP, it's been relevant.  At $10 for a used copy, you can't go wrong and it's an excellent reference: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0782129781/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you mean counting the number of characters in a string?  That's very simple

```
Dim strWord As String
Dim lngNumberOfCharacters as Long

strWord = "habit"
lngNumberOfCharacters = Len(strWord)
Debug.Print lngNumberOfCharacters
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Len(word)
```

Although that's not what your question title asks =)

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
word = "habit"
findchar = 'b"
replacechar = ""
charactercount = len(word) - len(replace(word,findchar,replacechar))
```

Comment: A brief explanation would improve this answer.

Comment: Ingenious!  It works by removing the characters to find.

Comment: This is a dang clever answer.

Answer (score 8):

Len is what you want.

```
word = "habit"  
length = Len(word)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the Len function

```
length = Len(myString)
```