# How do I split a row of text into different columns according to number of characters using a macro in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I want to know if I can use a macro in Excel to separate data in a single column into different colums according to number of characters. For example, what I have is this in column A

A

AB

ABC

1A

564

8

What I need is this, in colums A, B and C

A AB ABC

8 1A 564

Thanks.

Comment: To answer your question yes you can, but as this is not a code for me service take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725089/which-command-in-vba-can-count-the-number-of-characters-in-a-string-variable and have a crack. If you get stuck come back with your code and I'm sure people will be willing to help.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following formula in a new column B next to Column A:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$1:$A$6)=1,ROW($A$1:$A$6),99999),ROW()),1),"")
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time

and drag it down, it will write the Values of B whose Length is 1, and when it gives empty it means no more Values with Length 1
Small will find the Cell which length is 1 (Row()=1, 1st cell which length=1, Row()=2, 2nd cell which length =1 ...)
If will return all the rows for the corresponding condition
Index will return the Cell
Iferror return empty "" if no more match
For the second column write 2 instead of 1 in LEN($A$1:$A$6)=2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$1:$A$6)=2,ROW($A$1:$A$6),99999),ROW()),1),"")
```

For the third column write 3 in LEN($A$1:$A$6)=3

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$1:$A$6)=3,ROW($A$1:$A$6),99999),ROW()),1),"")
```